# Application in Tomcat is not responding

Tags: java, tomcat7

We are trying to access an application from the tomcat which is on a different host, but it is not loading even though the tomcat is running. It was running fine for the past 3 months. We restarted the tomcat now it is working fine.

But, we could not able to zero in on what happened.

Any idea how to trace / what might have caused this?

The CPU usage was normal and the tomcat memory was 1205640.

the memory setting of tomcat are 1024- 2048(min-max)

We are using tomcat 7.

Help much appreciated....thanks in advance.....cheers!!

Comment: I had the same problem, it would because of firewall, but sometimes connections doesn't get by the tomcat implicitly, maybe HTTPD or Jetty, something is here, and by default some http servers doesn't support remote connections

Comment: but restarting tomcat helped and it is working fine on the same port... if it is related to the firewall doesn't it will be affecting after the restart too?

Comment: what is your OS? and do you use http server?

Comment: windows server 2008 r2 strandard sp1 64-bit

Comment: and does tomcat http connection supported by IIS or httpd? if it's httpd you need to set the config.xml inside the httpd Catalina. and did you check the http logs in tomcat?

Comment: we are directly using tomcat and not apache, iis or jetty FYI

Comment: strange!@#$ always winnt problems with other M$-products! I'm sorry but I have no exact idea about it, maybe windows block the port because of to much connection, IDK, but try to check the http log in apache when you get nothing, possibility of firewall!

Comment: Did you have a look at that Tomcat instance's log to see if that gave you a hint?

Comment: Check tomcat logs, you will definitely find some information there..

Comment: No we have tried looking into the t-logs but no information there or we are missing something.... you guys remember any keywords for such log analysis?? that would help a lot...;-)

Answer (score 2):

...also - not sure on Windows - you may be running out of file descriptors. This typically happens when streams are not properly closed in finally blocks.

In addition, check with `netstat` if you have a lot of sockets remaining open or accumulating in wait state.

Less likely, the application is creating threads and never releasing them.

The application is leaking something (memory, file descriptors, sockets, threads,...) and running over a limit.

There are different ways to track this. A profiler may help or more simply, running JVM dumps at regular intervals and checking what is accumulating. The excellent [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) will help you analyze the dumps.

Answer (score 1):

Memory leak problems are not uncommon. If your Tomcat instance was running for three months and suddenly the contained application became unresponsive maybe that was the case. One solution (and if your resources allow you to do so) could be monitoring that Tomcat instance though **JMX** using **jconsole** to see how it behaves

Comment: `@morgano` I deployed and tested my database application using Tomcat 7. Absolutely hated it, useless junk and memory leaks all over the place. Alas this is such an engine that makes you feel bad about using servlets with Java.